# What is the efficient way for null check in forEach loop?

Tags: foreach, java-8, nullpointerexception, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to do null check in a forEach loop using this code but this is somehow failing

```
commonEntities.forEach(common -> {
        Long contractedQty = getContractedQty(common.getProducts());
        String productName = nonNull(common.getProducts().get(0).getProductId()) //here i am getting NullPointerexception
                ? productMap.get(common.getProducts().get(0).getProductId()).getName() //here i am getting NullPointer exception
                : StringUtils.EMPTY;

    .......
    });
}
```

is there any efficient way which i am use

Comment: Fix your data class so that `common.getProducts()` *never* returns null and never accepts null for the products list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Don’t add a dependency to an external library for the sake of getting an empty string. Just use `""`. And don’t repeat yourself. Instead of writing `common.getProducts().get(0).getProductId()` two times in a row, use local variables to remember the value. Then, inserting a null check for those variables will be easy.

Answer (score 2):

I like chaining `Optional`s.

```
String productName = Optional.ofNullable(common.getProducts())
  .filter(p -> !p.isEmpty())
  .map(p -> p.get(0))
  .map(Product::getProductId)
  .orElse(StringUtils.Empty);
```

or

```
String productName = Optional.ofNullable(common.getProducts())
  .stream()
  .map(Collection::stream)
  .map(Product::getProductId)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(StringUtils.Empty);
```

or maybe `stream()` the product list directly if it's guaranteed to be non-null, ie `common.getProducts().stream().map(Product::getProductId)`.

Comment: how i will map the getName()